# Best practice to store/pass a v8 promise resolver for later use? (In conjunction with C++ threads)

Tags: javascript, c++, v8

I'm trying to use v8 to expose an async "readFile" function to javascript. 
This function gets a path from javascript and immediately returns a promise,then creates a new thread to load the file, and finally schedules an event that will resolve the promise in the main thread.

Initially I've tried to pass the resolver via lambda captures, but that occasionally caused crashes in the v8 copy function, presumably when the lambda thread copied the Resolve object at the same time as the main thread tried to use it or something like that.

After fixing the crashes, the current version now stores the resolver in an unordered_map and now its the key that is passed via lambda captures, so that the scheduled event can retrieve the resolver later on.

This doesn't feel right, however, and it seems kind of wasteful in performance critical scenarios. Is there any way to pass the resolver directly to the lambda? Or is there another recommended way to handle this scenario?

```
typedef Persistent<Promise::Resolver, CopyablePersistentTraits<Promise::Resolver>> PersistentResolver;
static unordered_map<long long, PersistentResolver> resolvers;
static long long resolverID = 0;

V8Helper::_instance->registerFunction("readFileAsync", [](const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
    auto isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();

    String::Utf8Value fileUTF8(args[0]);
    string file = *fileUTF8;

    Local<Promise::Resolver> resolver = v8::Promise::Resolver::New(isolate);

    args.GetReturnValue().Set(resolver->GetPromise());

    // store resolver in a map, to find it later when it's ready to resolve
    long long currentID = resolverID++;
    resolvers[currentID] = PersistentResolver(isolate, resolver);

    thread t([file, isolate, currentID](){
        vector<char> buffer = loadFile(file);

        schedule([currentID, isolate, buffer]() {
            Local<ArrayBuffer> v8Buffer = v8::ArrayBuffer::New(Isolate::GetCurrent(), buffer.size());

            auto v8Data = v8Buffer->GetContents().Data();

            memcpy(v8Data, buffer.data(), buffer.size());

            auto persistantResolver = resolvers[currentID];
            Local<Promise::Resolver> resolver = Local<Promise::Resolver>::New(isolate, persistantResolver);
            resolver->Resolve(v8Buffer);

            resolvers.erase(currentID);
        });

    }); 
    t.detach();

});
```

Comment: For C++ part, you can use lambda capture with initializer to *move* an object, like `[a = std::move(b)] () {}`, C++14 is required. `v8::Persistent` doesn't support move semantics, but `v8::Global` supports. So replacing your `Persistent` with `Global` and use the move capturing in lambda should work.

Answer (score 0):

In order to continue using `v8::Persistent`, there is another way: you wrap the persistent in a `std::shared_ptr` and pass it to the lambda, which creates a copy (increasing the reference count) that keeps the `v8::Persistent` alive as long as the lambda itself is alive.

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<v8::Persistent<v8::Promise::Resolver>> persistentResolver =
    std::make_shared<v8::Persistent<v8::Promise::Resolver>>(isolate, resolver);
// ...
schedule([persistentResolver]() {
  v8::Isolate *isolate = v8::Isolate::GetCurrent();
  persistentResolver->Get(isolate)->Resolve(isolate->GetCurrentContext(), data).Check();
});
```

The approach with `v8::Global` mentioned by @llllllllll sounds good in principle, but leads to limitations if you try to store this lambda in a `std::function`, since that makes the `std::function` no longer copy-constructible. Wrapping the `v8::Persistent` in a `std::shared_ptr` doesn't have this limitation.